# sort an arraylist of arraylist of integers

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking to sort an arraylist of arraylist of integers and I require help?

I was informed that I need to implement comparator or comparable and then use the collection.sort to sort the list of list in order...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> g = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()

If you look at the list of list as the following example:
C1 – 5,4,10
C2 – 3,2,1
C3 – 7,8,6
First it will be sorted like this:
C1 – 4,5,10
C2 – 1,2,3
C3 – 6,7,8
Then it will be sorted like this
C1 – 1,2,3
C2 – 4,5,6
C3 – 7,8,10
```

Comment: basically you want to combine all arraylist into one big arraylist then sort it and then assign it back to the arraylist ?

Comment: How do you define the order of the list of integer? i.e. how would you put one list before another? It looks like how you would sort words in dictionary in your example, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No error check for null lists, but here it is.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(10, 5, 4), 
        Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 6));
for (List<Integer> l : list) {
    Collections.sort(l);
}
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
        return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
    }
});
System.out.println(list);
```

With Java 8 it gets even more concise:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(10, 5, 4),
                Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 6));
list.forEach(Collections::sort);
Collections.sort(list, (l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)));
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Javadoc on Collections.sort -> `Implementation Note:
This implementation defers to the List.sort(Comparator) method using the specified list and comparator.`--  I suppose you could avoid this redirection and use `l.sort(null);` and `list.sort(new Comparator...`.  In otherwords, I think you can write this all with the `List` object, no need for `Collections`... not that it matters...readability?

Comment: @Alex Would this approach work if the inner ArrayLists are of different length ?

Comment: @Alex Also why are you only comparing the first values of the list? What if the first terms are equal ?

Answer (score 6):

You could just sort each list individually. The `Collections.sort(collection)` will sort the Integers in ascending order automatically.

Answer (score 1):

if sort doesnt have what u need you can try this algorithm:

```
package drawFramePackage;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;
public class QuicksortAlgorithm {
    ArrayList<AffineTransform> affs;
    ListIterator<AffineTransform> li;
    Integer count, count2;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuicksortAlgorithm();
    }
    public QuicksortAlgorithm(){
        count = new Integer(0);
        count2 = new Integer(1);
        affs = new ArrayList<AffineTransform>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 128; i++){
            affs.add(new AffineTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, new Random().nextInt(1024), 0));
        }
        affs = arrangeNumbers(affs);
        printNumbers();
    }
    public ArrayList<AffineTransform> arrangeNumbers(ArrayList<AffineTransform> list){
        while (list.size() > 1 && count != list.size() - 1){
            if (list.get(count2).getTranslateX() > list.get(count).getTranslateX()){
                list.add(count, list.get(count2));
                list.remove(count2 + 1);
            }
            if (count2 == list.size() - 1){
                count++;
                count2 = count + 1;
            }
            else{
            count2++;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public void printNumbers(){
        li = affs.listIterator();
        while (li.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(li.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() { 
            public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) { 
                int min = Math.min(o1.size(),o2.size());
                for(int i=0;i<min;i++)
                {
                     if(o1.get(i)!=o2.get(i))
                     {
                         return o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i));
                     }
                }
                return (o1.size()<=o2.size())? -1:1;                
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will check up to last element of the list and sort them according to the requirement.

```
Collections.sort(res, new MIN());
```

//method

```
static class MIN implements Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>
    {
        public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> a,ArrayList<Integer> b)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<Math.min(a.size(),b.size());i++)
            {
                if(a.get(i)>b.get(i)) return 1;
                else if(a.get(i)<b.get(i)) return -1;
                else continue;
            }
            return a.size()-b.size();
        }
    }
```