# Sorting an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integers in which inner Lists are of varying lengths

Tags: java

**Ques:** Given a set of distinct integers, S, return all possible subsets. Elements in a subset must be in non-descending order. Also, the subsets should be sorted in ascending ( lexicographic ) order.
**My Approach:** I sorted the input first. Then found all the subsets and appended the new subsets found in each step to the "res". Now I tried sorting the "res" arraylist using custom comparator. But the output is coming wrong.
                     For the input arraylist `a={  15, 12, 4  }`
Output : `res={  {}, {4}, {4,12}, {4,15}, {4,12,15}, {12}, {12,15}, {15}  }`
Expected Output:`res={  {}, {4}, {4,12}, {4,,12,15}, {4,15}, {12}, {12,15}, {15}  }`

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(ArrayList<Integer> a) 
{   int i,j;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp;
    res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());        
    Collections.sort(a);   
    for(i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {   ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> str=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(ArrayList<Integer> al:res)
        {   temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            temp.addAll(al);
            temp.add(a.get(i));             
            str.add(temp);
        }
        res.addAll(str);

    }
    Collections.sort(res,new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>()
    {   public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> p,ArrayList<Integer> q)
        {   if(q.size()==0)
                return 1;
            else                        
                return Integer.compare(p.get(0),q.get(0));
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

To sort the inner lists with respect to each other I wrote this Comparator. But the Comparator is giving wrong answer. I suppose my Comparator is wrongly written.

Comment: What happens if `p.size()` is 0?

Comment: if you check `q.size() == 0` you also should check `p`. BTW: use `List#isEmpty` instead of `.size() == 0`

Comment: In the example given, what is the intended output? Try a minimal working example and update the question with given and desired output.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `[[12, 15], [15]]` when I use your comparator.

Comment: What's the expected output if `p.get(0) == q.get(0)` and another index differ?

Comment: now your code return `[[], [4],    [4, 12],    [4, 15], [4, 12, 15], [12],    [12, 15], [15]]` not `{  {4}, {4,12}, {4,15}, {4,12,15}, {12}, {12,15}, {15}  }` ?

Comment: @YCF_L Aren't both statements same?

Comment: there are the empty field in the beginning

Comment: @YCF_L Oops!! Corrected it. Now recheck .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't just compare the first elements of the lists. What happens when you compare two lists with the same first element, but an arbitrary number of different elements after it?

To alleviate the issue, you'll have to compare each element until a difference is reached. I would suggest the following:

```
int oneSize = listOne.size();
int twoSize = listTwo.size();

for(int i = 0; i < oneSize; i++)
{
    if(i == oneSize || i == twoSize)
        return oneSize - twoSize;

    int elementOne = listOne.get(i);
    int elementTwo = listTwo.get(i);
    if(elementOne == elementTwo)
       continue;

    return Integer.compare(elementOne, elementTwo);
}
```

Comment: Then why does this approach(comparing first terms) work over here     https://stackoverflow.com/a/10794240/8063278

Comment: @GaurangSinghal Did you try the solution with 2 or more lists with the same first element, but then different elements after?

Comment: I perfectly understand the logic and reasoning behind your solution approach. What I am asking is whether the solution given in the link I have posted is correct or not ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant did you try the solution in the link you gave me with the appropriate conditions? It appears that the solution would run into the same issue, as it checks only the first terms of the lists.

Comment: I agree. Seeing the upvotes and green tick I thought that I was missing something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort the inner lists individually first followed by sorting of the outer list.

The code snippet below worked for me.

```
Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {

                Collections.sort(p);
                Collections.sort(q);

                return Integer.compare(p.get(0),q.get(0));
            }
        });
```

**Output:**

```
Before Sorting
[12, 15] 
[25, 15] 
[10, 12, 25] 
After Sorting 
[10, 12, 25] 
[12, 15] 
[15, 25]
```

**Edit:**

Please find the below code which worked for me.

```
public class Stack1 {

    private List<List<Integer>> outerList = null;
    private List<Integer> innerList = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack1 stack1 = new Stack1();

        List<Integer> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
        fullList.add(15);
        fullList.add(12);
        fullList.add(4);

        stack1.subsetsOfList(fullList);

        System.out.println("Before Sorting");
        stack1.printLists();
        stack1.sortLists();
        System.out.println("After Sorting");
        stack1.printLists();
    }

    public void subsetsOfList(List<Integer> a) {
        int i, j;
        outerList = new ArrayList<>();
        outerList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        Collections.sort(a);
        for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            List<List<Integer>> str = new ArrayList<>();
            for (List<Integer> al : outerList) {
                innerList = new ArrayList<>();
                innerList.addAll(al);
                innerList.add(a.get(i));
                str.add(innerList);
            }
            outerList.addAll(str);
        }
    }

    public void printLists() {
        for (List<Integer> list : outerList) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }

    public void sortLists() {
        Collections.sort(outerList, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(List<Integer> t, List<Integer> t1) {

                Collections.sort(t);
                Collections.sort(t1);

                for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
                    if(t.size() > i && t1.size() > i) {
                        int result = Integer.compare(t.get(i), t1.get(i));
                        if(result != 0) {
                            return result;
                        } 
                    } else if (t.size() > i && t1.size() < i) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (t.size() < i && t1.size() > i) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }

                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
Before Sorting
[]
[4]
[12]
[4, 12]
[15]
[4, 15]
[12, 15]
[4, 12, 15]
After Sorting
[]
[4]
[4, 12]
[4, 12, 15]
[4, 15]
[12]
[12, 15]
[15]
```

Comment: Kindly recheck my post.

Comment: Kindly check the output of your code for input : [ [4], [12], [4,12], [15], [4,15], [12,15], [4,12,15]  ]

Comment: It works fine. You don't need to sort the lists inside the comparator as they already are in sorted order .